# Empty List is Sorted?

Tags: sorting

Is an empty list considered to be sorted?

Let's say I have a math function `sort` that sorts a list of numbers.

`sort :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]`

The above function definition (written in Haskell) means that the function's input is a list of any type 'a', and then its output is a list of that same input type.

`(Eq a)` means that we can must be able to compare the list's elements.

Example: `a` could be a number since numbers can be compared for equality.

From a math point of view, is an empty List considered to be sorted?

Comment: Sure. There is no pair $(a,b)$ of list elements such that $a$ comes before $b$ in the list, but $b < a$ (for whichever ordering '$<$' you consider).

Comment: Yes, an empty list is considered sorted.

Comment: thanks. and I suppose that there's no `minimum` of an empty List?

Comment: A list with just 1 element is also considered sorted

Comment: There is no minimum of an empty list, true. The sum of an empty list of numerics should be zero, and if your type has a minimum, then you could take the minimum element of your list to be the minimum value of that type, but in general, there is no minimum element of a list.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews No, you want $\min(A\cup B)=\min(\min(A),\min(B))$, so the only reasonable way to define the minimum of an empty set or list is the maximum of the possible values.

Comment: "Maximum of the possible values" is meaningless when you are just talking about the empty set - there is no set of possible values. Your set of values might be $[0,1]$ or $[0,\infty)$ or some uncountable linear order. In any event, you'd want a supremum of the possible values. And a supremum might not exist in the set of possible values. @ChristianSievers

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I meant "maximum of possible values" in the same spirit as your "if your type has a minimum". If no maximum existed, but a supremum did, then indeed I could use that, but I might be more reluctant to do it.